# How do you position a div in Internet Explorer 9 using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer-9

This Javascript doesn't seem to work in IE9 but works fine in Chrome.

```
function setDivPosition(nm,l,t)
{   
  document.getElementById(nm).style.left = l;
  document.getElementById(nm).style.top = t;
}
```

Comment: What values do `nm`, `l` and `y` have? What other styles apply to the element? What rendering mode (Quirks? Standards? Compatibility?) are you in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following and check:

```
document.getElementById(nm).style.left = l+"px";
document.getElementById(nm).style.top = t+"px";
```

I am assuming that l and t are numeric values.